# количество совпадений в таблице sql. Правильно ли так

Tags: sql

Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли составлен sql запрос

Есть две таблицы в одной заголовки опросов: название, описание, начало, конец. Во второй варианты ответа. Связаны они по id из первой таблицы. 
Хочу сделать запрос, который бы собирал инфу об опросе и количество вариантов ответа. Такой запрос будет праивльным?

```
select f.id, f.name, f.desc, f.active, f.startAt, f.finishAt, 
(SELECT count(*) from forms_elements e where e.formID = f.id) as 
conut_question , from forms f order by f.id desc
```

спасибо за помощь

Comment: Ну если не считать лишней запятой, запрос формально верен, если f.id есть первичный ключ или хотя бы уникальное поле. Но разумнее избавиться от подзапроса, переписав это дело на JOIN.

Comment: Спасибо. Я пробовал таким запросом 

select f.id, f.name, f.desc, f.active, f.startAt, f.finishAt, count(f.id) from forms f left join forms_elements e on e.formID = f.id group by f.id

но здесь проблема с left join. Из таблицы forms попадают все опросы. И когда я беру count, то у запросов без вариантов ответа количество получается равным 1

Comment: Вот интересно, если нужно количество вариантов ОТВЕТОВ, почему ты считаешь количество идентификаторов ВОПРОСА?

Comment: вот блин я тупой .. спасибо за помощь!!